# Take snapshoot from MapBox mapView (Android)

Tags: android, android-mapview, mapbox, snapshot

I want to get a picture from a MapBox MapView, but only returns a transparent image with MapBox Logo.

[Transparent snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1mHW.png)

This is the code, thanks!:

```
 public File getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);

        File file = new File(Utils.getAppFolder() + currentTrack.getDate().toString().replace(" ", "_").replace(":","_") + ".png");

        try{
            file.createNewFile();
        }catch(IOException e){
            Utils.logError("IOException: Exception in create new File: " + e.toString() );
        }

        FileOutputStream fileos = null;
        try{
            fileos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            Log.e("FileNotFoundException",e.toString());
        }

        returnedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fileos);
        return file;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!,

Here is the explanation and the code to fix this issue

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3677

Answer (score 0):

First add permission to save file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And this is the code:

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get same result with black background (because is a JPEG, and mine was a PNG). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perform snapshot of current MapView state with notifying listener about it. This method is asynchronous so it does not block calling thread. OnSnapshotReady.onSnapshotReady is called from non UI thread.

```
mapView.snapshot{bitmap->}
```